# iOS: Unlink library

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-construction, static-libraries

There is a library that causes **build errors when the project builds for the simulator**.

Is there a way to set a flag in the `build settings` or somewhere else to **make the compiler NOT link the specific library** when building for the simulator?

*This could be done by creating a new Target, but I would prefer not having to create a whole new target.*

**What would be the most convenient solution for something like this?** (which works both in XCode 4 and 5)

Comment: But if you don't link the library how will the code that relies on it continue to work?

Comment: This is only for testing purposes. I would not need that specific feature in the simulator, but would like to test other things.

Comment: So is it weak linked into the binary?

Comment: Yes, it is. Since the lib does not support i386, the linker returns with an error.

Comment: Oh, I just realized, it was not the linker that was complaining, it was the compiler. The linker actually ignored the lib, but the code was obviously missing the lib.

Thanks, your comments helped me correct the problem!

Comment: Is it a framework? You can set it to optional, if so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `#ifdef` out the `#import` calls to the library using:

```
#ifdef TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#import <...>
#endif
```

If you do that then the code won't try to link with the library.